# Why did Molly Bloom tip the front desk man in such a manner?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

In the movie *Molly's Game*, Molly gets beaten up by a mobster after she turns down their initial offer for protection. What happens is:

1. Molly turns down mob's offer and returns to her upscale apartment.
2. The front desk man tells Molly she has got a package coming up.
3. Molly gets back to her apartment and opens the door when someone is knocking it.
4. Molly gets beaten up and some of her money are taken away.
5. Molly hides in her room for a few days to mend her wounds.
6. Molly gets out of her apartment, on her way out, the front desk guy talks to Molly again. She turns around put some cash into his pocket, pat him on his shoulder and says: I guess I did not tip you enough last Christmas before walking off.

Why does Molly do this? Especially the way Molly pats his should and he looks down in shame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did the men who beat her up had a package with them? If not then they paid the doorman to let them in, tell them what apartament Molly lives in and made him not check on her later and call the police.

Molly realized that and paid the man "for later" if the mobster decide to come back. The pat on the shoulder is typical to show a person who is higher in the hierarchy (the patted one is lower).

Comment: yeah, I initially thought it was Molly's driver / body guard betrayed her, as it was him who set up a meeting between Molly and mobs.